# Bind DataTable To Textbox UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, user-controls

I searched a lot for this problem but i did not find any clear post about that.

I do databinding with this command:

```
userControl11.DataBindings.Clear();
userControl1.DataBindings.Add( "Text",dt,"DM" );
```

I also put `dt`
for datagridview datasource.

this work for usual controls but not for usercontrols.

Now the Text of the usercontrol does not change if i select different rows of datagridview and it is always empty.

I think this problem is simple.Should I use `INotifyPropertyChanged` ?

Comment: Any Body doesnt have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew the answer is simple!

simply I did this in Usercontrol :

```
  public override string Text
    {
        get { return txtmoney.Text; }
        set
        {

            txtmoney.Text = value;

        }
    }
```

And this to bind in my form :

```
uctextbox1.DataBindings.Add( "text",DT,"DM" );
```